# How two compare two JSON objects array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have JSON objects array as shown below. The following JSON objects array is in the file **(process/ptp-hello.json)**

```
{
    "list": ["1", "2"],
    "code": ["ABCD", "DEFG", "PQRT", "KJHG", "OOPO", "MNBG", "IUYT"]
}
```

**Php code:**

```
<?php
if (file_exists('process/ptp-hello.json')) {
    $letter = json_decode(file_get_contents('process/ptp-hello.json'));  // Line A
}
?>

<?php foreach ($letter->list as $key => $value) { ?>
    <a href="/en/?s=&port=<?php echo $letter->code[$value]; ?>">
        <div class="beats">
            <div class="color-green"><?php echo $letter->code[$value]; ?></div>    // Line B 
        </div>
    </a>
<?php }
```

Line B prints **DEFG** and **PQRT**

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code above so that it prints ABCD, KJHG, OOPO, MNBG and IUYT.

In short, I want to remove those elements from `code` whose indices are listed in `list`

Comment: I'm not sure I full understand your question. Do you mean you want to remove those elements from `code` whose indices are listed in `joint_committees`?

Comment: @CherryDT Yes, you are right. .

Comment: @CherryDT I will update my question with your lines.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter the codes like this :

```php
$remainingCodes = array_diff_key($data_house->code, array_flip($data_house->joint_committees));

var_dump($remainingCodes);
// array(5) { [0]=> string(4) "CACN" [3]=> string(4) "CIMM" [4]=> string(4) "ENVI" [5]=> string(4) "ETHI" [6]=> string(4) "FAAE" }
```

Then you can loop over the `$remainingCodes` variable.

This is how it works :

1. Flip the keys and values of `$data_house->joint_committees` array with [`array_flip`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip)
2. Remove the keys of `$data_house->code` corresponding to the values of the last array with [`array_diff_key`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php)

Comment: I was first making sure to convert `joint_committees` values to integers, but it doesn't seems to change anything, even with `strict_types` in PHP7+

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to achieve this, three are listed below:

#### 1. Iterate over `code` but don't print anything if key exists in `joint_committees`

```php
<?php foreach ($data_house->code as $key => $value) {
    if (!in_array($key, $data_house->joint_committees) { ?>
        <!-- Your HTML here -->
    <?php }
}
```

Note: This could also be done by having `if (!in_array($key, $data_house->joint_committees) continue;` without putting putting the HTML into the condition.

#### 2. Loop over `joint_committees` first and remove any matching items from `code`

```php
<?php
for ($data_house->joint_committees as $index) {
    $data_house->code = array_splice($data_house, $index, 1);
}

foreach ($data_house->code as $value) { ?>
    <!-- Your HTML here -->
<?php }
```

Note: You could also use `unset($data_house->code[$index])` but it would leave a "weird" array with non-consecutive indices.

#### 3. Map `code` to an array without the `joint_committees` indices

```php
<?php
$filteredCodes = array_filter($data_house->code, function ($key) use ($data_house) {
    return !in_array($key, $data_house->joint_committees)
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

foreach ($filteredCodes as $value) { ?>
    <!-- Your HTML here -->
<?php }
```

Note: Starting with PHP 7.4, the `array_filter` call can be simplified to this:

```php
$filteredCodes = array_filter($data_house->code, fn($key) => !in_array($key, $data_house->joint_committees), ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

---

**Update:** Another, probably even more elegant solution was proposed by Brewal [in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60640418/1871033). :-)

Comment: Hi, I hope all is well. I have one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64716437/how-to-get-next-month-dates-in-json-object-array). It's not similar. I am wondering if you can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as

```
$json = '{
"joint_committees": ["1", "2"],
"code": ["CACN", "CHPC", "CIIT", "CIMM", "ENVI", "ETHI", "FAAE"]
}';

$data_house = json_decode($json, true);


foreach($data_house['code'] as $key => $val) {
    if(!in_array($key, $data_house['joint_committees'])) {
        echo $key . ' ' . $val ."\n";
    }
}
```

This returns

```
0 CACN
3 CIMM
4 ENVI
5 ETHI
6 FAAE
```

You can do a lot with the return, make a new array, echo out information, whatever you'd like to do.